# Xamarin.Forms TimePicker "Time" Binding not settable?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

On multiple `Views` I have `TimePickers` which I would like to set to a certain time but they always show `00:00`.
They are set up like this:

```
<controls:ExtendedTimePicker VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                             TextColor="#FFFFFF"
                             Time="{Binding SaveTime, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Or llike this:

```
<TimePicker Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Format="HHmm"
            Time="{Binding SaveTime, Mode=TwoWay}"
            BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

For clarification, `ExtendedTimePicker` is from the `Xlabs.Forms` library. As it inherits from the `TimePicker`, it has the very same issue. Also I've tried every binding mode there is, but all of them got me the same result of `00:00`.

In my `ViewModels` I've tried to set the bound property in the constructor, delay it for some hundred miliseconds, or set it when a specific Message from the `MessagingCenter` is received. No matter when I set it, the displayed time never changes. The getter of the bound property is accessed after I set the Property to a certain time though.
The Property is defined as:

```
private TimeSpan _SaveTime;
public TimeSpan SaveTime
{
    get { return _SaveTime; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _SaveTime, value); }
}
```

`SetProperty` leads to this:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : IViewModel, IDisposable
{
    protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var eventHandler = PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

So, is this a bug? Is there something to fix this? A workaround? Something? Maybe an update?
I am working with:
VisualStudio 2017 15.2
Xamarin 4.5.0
Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.267

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, shame on me. I had a custom renderer for `TimePicker` and `ExtendedTimePicker` which fixed another bug in an older version of Xamarin.Forms where the `TimePickerDialog` would always be in `12H` format no matter what I entered as format. After removing the class from my code, everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your Property from your ViewModel by using this code in order to ensure it is set by the UI thread:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => SaveTime = yourTimeSpan);
```

If, it is not Ok, can you post the line where you set the property?

Comment: I tried your line in the constructor of that `ViewModel` but had no success. I went even further and set the private field of that property to `private TimeSpan _SaveTime = new TimeSpan(15, 14, 13);` so that the very first access to this property would return a `TimeSpan` that is not `00:00:00`. Same result, the `TimePicker` is showing `00:00` despite the property returning `15:14:13` (checked that with breakpoints).

Comment: Even giving the TimePicker a `x:Name`, and setting the time in the CodeBehind achieved nothing. Still `00:00`